# Android / Java: How to get last row value in sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello I am using a sqlite database in my android application, and I have question:
I am trying to get the last value text(thats the collumn) from the last row from the table TABLE_XYZ... but it does not work.. i am using the following code...what am I doing wrong?

another question is, how can I return two values instead of only one, when I want to get several values from the last row like column text and message?

```
private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";
```

...

```
String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_XYZ+" ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
     cursor.close();
    return cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT) );
```

EDIT:

i hade some errors in my Query,, i fixed it, but still have errors:

```
    String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_XYZ +  " ORDER BY " +  KEY_TEXT+ " DESC LIMIT 1";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    String str =  cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT );
    cursor.close();
    return str;
```

while debugging I can see that cursor does have the right values inside... but when i try to get the column value with this command "cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT );"... it does not work...

Comment: if you want only the 1 record you should use LIMIT check out my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are closing cursor before getting it's value

try this :

```
String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_XYZ+" ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
String str = "";
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    str  =  cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT) );
cursor.close();
return str;
```

Comment: thank you for your help - I changed my code (see edit) - but it still does not work.. i think the command "cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT );" is wrong to get the column value.

Comment: see my updated answer. you should add `cursor.moveToFirst()` before getting value.

Answer (score 1):

From the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

abstract void  close() 
Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid.

You are closing the cursor before returningthe string.

Comment: yes, it was one of the errors - thank you I fixed that one :)

Answer (score 1):

Like @whatever5599451 said you should not close the cursor before you get value. Also try a query like this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT column FROM " + TABLE_XYZ + 
                     " ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1";
```

You can specify the columns also specify to return only 1 row.

This will bring back only the column you are ordering by you can also specify more columns example:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT column, column2, column3 FROM " + TABLE_XYZ + 
                     " ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1";
```

`*` means select all columns

Comment: @CL ya my bad should be LIMIT 1 I changed it

Comment: thank you, I changed my code - but stil have a error :S see my edit

Answer (score 0):

to get the last column, use the name of the column instead of " * "  (* means all, all the fields)

Comment: Why not get an array with *, and take the last element in the array?

Comment: with * you get all the columns for a row, and since you do not need all the columns... why get the unnecessary data from db?

Comment: Good point, maybe you can show how to do that. "You can do X" is generally not as good an answer as "This is how you do X".

Comment: String selectQuery= "SELECT " + KEY_TEXT + " FROM " + TABLE_XYZ + " ORDER BY " +  KEY_TEXT+ " DESC LIMIT 1";
@Verdolino: thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Steve: do this:

```
String selectQuery= "SELECT " + KEY_TEXT + " FROM " + TABLE_XYZ + " ORDER BY " + KEY_TEXT+ " DESC LIMIT 1";
```

then you get just one String with the last record containing just the right column