# android studio java auto verify if mysql database has been changed

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

i have to create an app which send a push notification if a value from mysql database has changed . 
I created **MainActivity** ,**LoginActivity** , **RegisterActivity** .
I did the register-login system and now i want to interogate the mysql db and if a value has been changed , I want to modificate a boolean variable in true and after have a if statement :

```
if (boolean variable == true ) { do push notification }.
```

My app now can read from php file a text, that text contains all database rows .
I tryed do something in `onCreate() method  string  X = text read;`
after do a while where receive that text for infinite and if that text is different that `String X ... boolean value = true` and after  I will do push notification but I don't know yet how to do push notification.

That didn't work because if I do a while infinite in `onCreate()`, the app show me white screen, that means app has didn't created.

I need some help, I'm a beginner in android but I some skills in java.

I want to know how to verify if a database row has changed and if that happen then show a push notification . and if you can tell me more about how to create a push notification after that.

I want also to know how make that while to work to read that php file to infinite  until the response text is changed.!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I completely understand you question, but let me try to answer

1) You have reached a point where you get

`if (boolean variable == true ) {
sendPushNotification()
}`
and you are not sure what you need to do for sending a push notification:

Please refer to [developer's doc](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html). Sharing a small code snippet:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service//

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
```

If your app is targtted for Android O, you need to make  [Notification channel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)

Comment: ok , that help me but i still have a problem to make  the app  know if a mysql database row has changed

Comment: If your data is in sqlite db you can do following steps 1) Get the Data using select query 2) Save the uniqueId/rowId in shared preference 3) Next time again get the data and compare the last stored data in shared preference if they are not same, means new row is inserted. Just google this steps, you will get the code. Try[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136940/android-java-how-to-get-last-row-value-in-sqlite

Comment: my db is msql not sqlite